# Ubuntu 19 installation on virt-manager freezes

Tags: virtualization

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu 19 on my virt-manager it freezes. I installed Windows 10 yesterday and it went fine, and I have other working ubuntu 18 instances which also work fine.

How can I debug what's happening? Is it a known problem?

Comment: No known issue right now, are you installing 19.04 or the current dev version 19.10? And what version is the host at? "it freezes" means virt-manager or the guest freezes? If so at what boot state?

Comment: Getting this with 19.10 desktop as well. 100% processor, all ram consumed.

Comment: This seems to be a problem with choosing Dvorak as a key board layout during the install.

Comment: happens to me too, the keyboard layout selected is irrelevant.